# How to make numerical integration of the sine wave from ADC

Tags: c, embedded, numerical-integration

I'm gathering data from ADC converter. I'm wondering how to perform numerical integration of the sine wave from ADC converter. When Im using trapezoidal rule I'm getting a result that is moved above x axis by 1.0. I can add an offset to the signal, but I don't know the integral Value of the first measured point.

```
float calka_oblicz(CALKA_STRUCT* calka, float period){

calka->currOut = (  (calka->currMeasurement)+(calka->prevMeasurement)   )*(period/2.0f);
calka->currOut = calka->currOut + calka->prevOut;

calka->prevMeasurement = calka->currMeasurement;
calka->prevOut = calka->currOut;

return (calka->currOut);}
```

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kilv.png)

Comment: What is the problem? Where is the offset? I do not see any offset on the plots

Comment: I mean - the integral plot should be -cos Wave without the 1.0 offset? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is but I think that you do not understand the difference between integral and definite integral. You calculate the second one. From 0 to PI such an integral is equal `2`

Comment: "that is moved above x axis by 1.0." ---> Which axis is your `x-axis` : _time_ or `currOut`?